# Why aren't there barlines in the piano solo parts in Beethoven's Piano Concerto No. 5?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

In the beginning of this piece you'll notice that the piano solo part has no barlines. Why? And why does he use 16th notes? How can a "16th" note have any meaning without barlines (not to mention triplets and septuplets)? Is this just a way to invite a virtuoso pianist to play it however she wants without the constraint of barlines?

[Score at imslp](https://imslp.org/wiki/Piano_Concerto_No.5%2C_Op.73_(Beethoven%2C_Ludwig_van))

[YouTube with score](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8K-eFmYXGh4)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a *[cadenza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadenza)*. The lack of barlines is, as you suppose, because Beethoven intends the performer to play in a rhythmically free, quasi-improvised manner. The pitch durations are intended to be suggestive -- relative to each other -- but not necessarily exact.

[image: Emperor concerto opening, part 1 of 2]

[image: Emperor concerto opening, part 2 of 2]

Another example is the opening of Chopin's [Etude in C# minor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBsfd6sGuLc), op. 25 no. 7. Notice that there is no time signature at the beginning. However, the editor of the score in the video has put in some suggested barlines as a guide to the performer. On the other hand, on IMSLP, [Mikuli's edition](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/7/70/IMSLP60297-PMLP01970-Chopin_Etudes_Schirmer_Mikuli_Op_25_scan.pdf) (below) does not include those.

[image: Chopin op. 25 no. 7 opening cadenza]

Another example comes from the final bar of Chopin's Etude in E minor, op. 25, no. 7 ([Mikuli's edition](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/7/70/IMSLP60297-PMLP01970-Chopin_Etudes_Schirmer_Mikuli_Op_25_scan.pdf) again)

[image: Chopin op. 25 no. 5 closing cadenza]

Also, regarding your question "How can '16th' note have any meaning without barlines", the answer is that the note values are not influenced by the presence of barlines. In strict tempo, a 16th is always the duration of two 32nds or half of an 8th. The note durations are only relative to each other. Barlines are, essentially, a convenience for reading -- so that you can easily see groupings of beats.

Comment: Barlines may be for the reader's convenience, but bars are not! Bars are super-important!