# Can music be arrhythmic?

Tags: theory, rhythm

The question is in the subject. Can music be arrhythmic(metrically) by the meaning of classical music theory?

Comment: Taking a stab.  As someone who has played a lot of music, but studied very little theory, I would say a collection of tones, and beats with no discernable pattern is just noise.

Comment: That depends on the concept you to use for "music". To most people used to western music even traditional music from beyond the East of Europe is considered arrhythmic.

Comment: @musicamante it also depends on the definition of "classical music theory."

Comment: Exhibit A: Krzysztof Penderecki - https://youtu.be/HilGthRhwP8

Comment: You might clarify why you put "metrically" in parenthesis. If you actually mean can music be non-metrical, that isn't the same as being without rhythm.

Comment: Certainly. Music is ultimately based on song or dance, and it is only dance that needs to be rhythmic.

Comment: This question is extremely vague in terms of its scope. What is arrhythmia in music, let alone classical? Without a pulse? There are pieces without time signatures, do those fit?

Comment: My choir has performed versions of Bach motets in which every note is drawn out a long time (many seconds) and every singer decides on their own when to move to the next note.  Doesn't get much more arrhythmic than that.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger can you define what a (discernable) pattern is? The usual definition of music is noise organized in time, but i'm curious about yours.

Comment: @AnswerMyQuestion Borrowing from the definition you cite, I would say notes are not organized in a repeating fashion at all.  The brain will make connections based on groupings in time, whether by a repeating interval, or intervals of a curve - one that could be graphed with smooth precision.  If you can't graph the notes to some well-defined function of time, then you will have cacophony.

Comment: Without delving into noise territory, there's also Murder Most Foul, by Bob Dylan. That's certainly music for my ears, but no rhythm as far as metronomes can count.

Answer (score 17):

The answer will be 'yes' for any definition of arrhythmic, as there are no rules about what music can and can't do - but it's probably still worth noting that it's not totally clear what 'arrhythmic' means without being more specific about the definition. Only a limited number of music styles are based on an entirely regular meter, with most styles allowing (or even assuming) a more flexible timing 'grid' on which events can fall. And even when we consider music with very little in the way of rhythmic repetition that would allow a meter to be discerned, the human brain is still likely to pick up rhythmic patterns from the timings of most possible clusters of events.

Some might say that a piece of music with a very low density of discernable events, such as an entirely steady drone, is 'arrhythmic', but others might require that for a piece of music to be 'arrhythmic' it should actively exhibit events that don't seem to adhere to a rhythm.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. There are a variety of ways metrically arrhythmic musical events can occur.

#### Aleatoric music

The idea behind aleatory is that musical events occur unpredictably. The primary modern example of this is John Cage's *Music of Changes* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Changes), [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRyb47cz5mo&list=OLAK5uy_kCIblLdqdZcieAt4jbqBGREMVYoZGFsK4))

Another example is [Joshua Banks Mailman's "comprovisation"](http://www.joshuabanksmailman.com/compositions/modern_compositions/multimedia.html) series, in which sensors are attached to the body, and musical meta-elements are controlled by body movements. (By meta-elements, I mean that movement doesn't directly affect the pitch, rather it affects the rate of change of pitch.) The technique is fully described in his article "Cybernetic Phenomenology of Music, Embodied Speculative Realism, and Aesthetics-Driven Techné for Spontaneous Audio-Visual Expression" (*Perspectives of New Music* vol. 54, no. 1, pp. 5–95 [2016]).

The [Wikipedia article on aleatoric music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleatoric_music) provides a wide variety of examples of music written in this way.

#### Free time

Music in "free time" is performed without a strict underlying pulse (meter); rather, the rhythmic timing is intuitive. The concept is discussed on SE MP&T: [Free time in music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/54605/free-time-in-music).

[The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_time_(music)) also gives a wide variety of examples.

#### Cadenza

The core idea behind a cadenza is that it be improvisational; thus, the meter may not be strict, and specific rhythms may or may not be discernible.

For example, see the following SE MP&T Q&A: [Why aren't there barlines in the piano solo parts in Beethoven's Piano Concerto No. 5?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/102248/why-arent-there-barlines-in-the-piano-solo-parts-in-beethovens-piano-concerto)

#### Rubato

Rubato is the stretching and compressing of musical time for expressive purpose. Although it maintains the rhythm, it can obscure the meter.

Comment: If you're gonna reference John Cage, we should mention one of his most well known "compositions": *4'33"*, which is literally just 4 minutes and 33 seconds of silence and ambient noise.  It is of course pushing the limits as to what qualifies as "music", but that was kind of the point.

Comment: Some handbell pieces include sections where players are supposed to ring selected bells at random times.  Typically there will be rhythmic indication for when the selection of bells should change, but I could imagine that a work that was designed to serve as incidental music for a play or narration might mark chord changes as occurring at certain points in the text, and such a piece could be characterized as arrhythmic.

Answer (score 8):

> Can music be arrhythmic(metrically) by the meaning of classical music theory?

I don't think you need to bring in "classical" theory. The essential meaning of *rhythm* is *periodicity*, something that repeats. You just need to have some music with no repeating element.

That could get a bit tricky philosophically, because you need to ask *what* elements repeat and what time scale are you considering. Even the theory of meter can get vague about what specifically creates the accent patterns of meter. In a certain way it is just presupposed to exist conceptually.

A simple beat is rhythmic, it repeats. Tempo changes don't necessarily mean arrhythmic. An accelerando and rubato change the tempo, but you wouldn't describe those as arrhythmic.

A drone seems an obvious possibility for arrhythmia, but even things like didgeridoo, bowed string, circular breathing have patterns. Eventually you breath in, the bow changes direction.

The human mind tries to find patterns (rhythms) and it seems there is significant flexibility about what can be identified as a pattern. I think you need to get into the avant-garde to have music that could truly be considered arrhythmic. You could go the John Cage route and call complete silence your music. You could turn on some sine wave generator and have drone a steady pitch and call it music. White noise: music. Etc, etc.

One final thought. Even in computer programming people will point out your can't have truly random numbers.

On a superficial level it seems easy to be random, but on a deeper philosophical level it's difficult.

Comment: Random and nonperiodic are not the same, I think. Or at least, random and non-repeating are not the same. So you're final sentence should be, "it seems easy to not repeat (rhythmically/time-wise), but [...] it's not".

Comment: Computer programming people will point out you can totally have random numbers, but pure computers can't generate them. You can build an actually random number generator and plug it into a computer, and now the computer can have actually random numbers whenever it likes!

Comment: @user253751 do you mean _pseudo_random? In computing they try to get natural sources of entropy for true randomness. My point is that special work needs to be done to be random.

Comment: @user253751 No I mean they can plug a natural source of entropy into a computer. You might argue it's not part of the computer itself, but the computer has the ability to access it.

Comment: @awelotta, I'm not sure what you mean. If it's something like "a sequence cannot be repeated in randomness", that isn't what I meant. Random means lack of pattern, there are degrees of randomness, and some philosophical sense that true randomness is impossible.

Comment: @user253751, that would be exactly the point, not part of a computation, more importantly, not trivial, not easy. And to the _actual_ point, in music it's in the realm of avant-garde.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis it's pretty trivial now that natural entropy sources are built into every CPU

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I meant, you say that the "essential meaning of *rhythm* is periodicity". Therefore, I don't get how pattern/randomness is relevant to rhythm.

Comment: @awelotta, what is the distinction you are making between rhythm, periodicity, pattern, etc? For all practical purposes the terms are synonymous. The relevance is that true randomness would lack a period by which you could divide up events in time into patterns.

Comment: @user253751 if this was StackOverflow then talking about what CPUs can do and what is trivial in programming would make sense. This is a different forum.

Answer (score 5):

European classical music theory could perhaps withstand the removal of the concept of rhythm, but it definitely depends on the concept of sequence, of events happening in a particular order.  Consider: most aspects of the analysis of a chorale harmonization or of a melody's structure would be unchanged if the durations of all the notes were changed to random values.  Indeed, much medieval music, notably liturgical chant, is preserved without any rhythmic information.  On the other hand, if you change the order of the notes, the pieces would quickly lose their identity.

Despite this, European classical music (indeed, European music generally) has been fundamentally rhythmic since techniques for recording rhythm were invented, and probably before.  Every other musical tradition with which I am familiar is also rhythmic to one degree or another.  (There are several such traditions, though I have only passing familiarity with them, including music of Ghana, Karnataka, and Java, of indigenous peoples of the Americas, and to a lesser extent Chinese opera.)

It also bears mention that rhythm and meter are not synonymous.  Much polyphonic music from the late middle ages and the early renaissance is not metrical in the modern sense, but it is clearly rhythmic.

Answer (score 3):

Drone music can fit that pattern. A single note or chord in this type of music can ring for so long before another one is struck that all sense of rhythmic connection between the two "events" is lost. This is also the case for ambient music in general (of which Drone is technically a subgenre).
Check out **Sunn O))) meets Nurse with Wound - The Iron Soul of Nothing** for an example.

Noise music can also be arrhythmic by definition of it being noise, although at the same time it's by definition not music, so I'm not sure it fits your criteria.

Comment: Notes/chords don't even need to be that long, if their start and end isn't clearly defined.  For example, the extremely reverberant, crossfading/overlapping notes in the [Cathedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathedral_Oceans) [Oceans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Su690udXSk&list=PLDfp4Ro1qTmd9QX4Ksaq4-n8NSPAu1mtf) series.

Answer (score 3):

An important division of extemporaneous music (*manodharma sangita*) in the Indian classical tradition is *rāga ālāpana*. In *rāga ālāpana*, the musician develops a *rāga* in a step-by-step fashion while obeying the structure and characteristics of the *rāga*, and this is done without any strict rhythm. So, this could be another example of arrhythmic music, to add to the other nice answers to this question.

Answer (score -1):

I hesitate to pretend to speak on this, since I know nearly nothing about it, but I am dimly aware that there are Africa-continent (and probably other) musical styles that involve mostly drums and percussion instruments, but/and at significantly different repetition rates, so that the whole thing only repeats itself after a considerable interval of time. In particular, listening to just some moments of the pieces might seem to be a cacophony. I hope someone here knows more about this.

(Question, then: does lack of small-scale pattern discourage us from believing in a large-scale pattern, by instinct?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyrhythm#Sub-Saharan_African_music_traditions I think you're overestimating/overstating the effect. I'm not an ethnomusicologist, but AFAIK there is still something like a bar, and it's relatively short.

Comment: This is actually the opposite of what the user was asking about I think.  Traditional African music tends to be much more heavily about the rhythm and less about tonality.  Certainly they use *different* and often more complex rhythms than classical European music, but it would be very wrong to refer to it as "arrhythmic".